# Проблемы с условием if

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, bs4

Вот у меня есть код.

```
import requests
import dateparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock=soup.find('div',{'id':'main_block'})
    title=mainblock.find('h1').text
    datetime=mainblock.find('span',{'class':'date'}).text
    text_content=mainblock.find('div',{'class':'text sharedText js-mediator-article'}).text
    print(datetime)


    #datetime=dateparser.parse(date, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])


    #return  ()

def main():
    url = 'https://tengrinews.kz/money/pyat-layfhakov-dlya-maksimalno-komfortnogo-pohoda-v-kino-375931/'
    (get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

И вот при выводе `datetime`У меня выводится в формате:"Сегодня 9:00 ".

Как создать такое условие чтобы условие переводило слово **"Сегодня"** на **"Today"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас в `datetime` у Вас хранится строка.
Для замены `сегодня` на `Today` необходимо вызвать `datetime.replace('сегодня', 'Today')`

Comment: Нет мне нужно именно условие,потому что страницы которые я парсю бывают что написано вчера.И также они могут написаны на другом языке.

Comment: В вопросе Вы задали конкретную страницу, я ответил по конкретной странице. 
Если Вам известны другие варианты, используйте методы строк, например str.find(), проверяете и если удовлетворяет - заменяете.

Comment: Хорошо.Я понял.Благодарю !